# Node JS: Electron problem with "electron.asar" file

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I have a NodeJS application that is packed with Electron to create a Windows x64 executable.
The packaged app works fine on the majority of the PC, but I don't know for what reason, in some PC the app fail randomly.

The error stack is:

```
"Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\app\app-desktop-win32-x64\resources\electron.asar\browser\api\dialog.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:453:3)
    at Object.func [as openSync] (electron/js2c/asar.js:138:31)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:353:35)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (electron/js2c/asar.js:580:40)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:850:22)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:633:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:625:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:739:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:14:16)"
```

Someone has fight against this error? Any idea or suggestion?

In some PC, the error disappear renaming the folder that contains the app, but in one PC, the error persist indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found how to do this.

I extract the asar files manually before pack and distribute my app and the problem gone.
Is a bit tedious, but is the unique solution that was valid for all the PC's.